# Variable-length argument list with "user-defined type" messing up arguments

Tags: java, variadic-functions

I've come a long way in the past two weeks since asking my first question, having written a tictactoe game using grid layout and button-pushes to make x and o and declare winner and a class that performs complex number arithmetic *(e.g., z1=-3-4i plus z2=7+i via cAdd(z1,z2))* and calculations (e.g., sin(z1) and log(z2)) correctly. (Confirmed by and implemented via help from a CAS called **Derive**.)

No problem so far.

So I decided to enhance cAdd to accept more than two complex numbers (e.g, cAdd(z1,z2,z3)) and found the following syntax for varying-length argument lists:

```
public ComplexNumber cAdd ( ComplexNumber ... a);
```

But whereas the two-parameter version of cAdd(z1,z2) works fine, the "varargs" version (e.g., cAdd(z1,z2,z3)) gives correct results BUT CHANGES THE PARAMETER VALUES so that if z1 is used in a later calculation, it's not what it started out as.

Here's code, followed by output.

```
  class ComplexNumber {

    double real, imag;

    public ComplexNumber() {                // default constructor
    }

    public ComplexNumber(double a, double b) {    // initializer constructor
        real = a;
        imag = b;
    }

  public class CBug {

    public static void cPrint(String s, ComplexNumber z) {
        System.out.println(s + z.real + " + " + z.imag + "i");
    }

    public static void dump(int n, ComplexNumber z, ComplexNumber [] a){
        System.out.print("Dump " + n + "; sum so far is " );
        cPrint("z = ", z);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
            cPrint("" + i + ": " ,a[i]);
        System.out.println("");
    }

    public static ComplexNumber cAdd(ComplexNumber ... a) {
        ComplexNumber z = a[0];
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++){
            dump(i,z,a);
            z.real = z.real + a[i].real;
            z.imag = z.imag + a[i].imag;
        }
        dump(99,z,a);
        return z;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ComplexNumber sum = new ComplexNumber();
        ComplexNumber z1 = new ComplexNumber(1000,500);
        ComplexNumber z2 = new ComplexNumber(7, 1);
        ComplexNumber z3 = new ComplexNumber(100,100);
        cPrint("z1 = ", z1);
        cPrint("z2 = ", z2);
        cPrint("z3 = ", z3);

        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("++++++++++++++++++++++");
        sum = cAdd(z1,    z2,    z3) ;
        cPrint     ("z1 + z2 + z3 = " , sum);
        System.out.println("--------------------");

        cPrint("z1 = ", z1);
        cPrint("z2 = ", z2);
        cPrint("z3 = ", z3);
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
run:
z1 = 1000.0 + 500.0i
z2 = 7.0 + 1.0i
z3 = 100.0 + 100.0i

++++++++++++++++++++++
Dump 1; sum so far is z = 1000.0 + 500.0i   [correct]
0: 1000.0 + 500.0i
1: 7.0 + 1.0i
2: 100.0 + 100.0i

Dump 2; sum so far is z = 1007.0 + 501.0i     [correct]
0: 1007.0 + 501.0i        [but WHY DID ARG[0] CHANGE to "z so far"?]
1: 7.0 + 1.0i
2: 100.0 + 100.0i

Dump 99; sum so far is z = 1107.0 + 601.0i   [correct]
0: 1107.0 + 601.0i         [WHY DID ARG[0] CHANGE AGAIN to new "z so far"?]
1: 7.0 + 1.0i
2: 100.0 + 100.0i

z1 + z2 + z3 = 1107.0 + 601.0i                [correct]
--------------------
z1 = 1107.0 + 601.0i          [WHY DID z1 (a.k.a. arg[0]) CHANGE?]
z2 = 7.0 + 1.0i
z3 = 100.0 + 100.0i
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Can't use 1st parameter in subsequent calculations since cAdd damaged it.

=============================

Here's what I now have for cAdd (since my original "fix" [described in comments below] was a bit wacko]:

```
 public static ComplexNumber cAdd(ComplexNumber ... a) {
    ComplexNumber z = new ComplexNumber();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++){
      z.real += a[i].real;
      z.imag += a[i].imag;
    }
    return z;
  }
```

===============================

Comment: Umm: `ComplexNumber z = a[0]; ... z.real = z.real + a[i].real;`

Comment: Oh, my. I got it. Dopey me, but I'm most assuredly a newbie.

Comment: //Passing reference, updating it.
z.real = z.real + a[i].real;// here you are changing it
z.imag = z.imag + a[i].imag;

Comment: My fix, thanks to Oli C:     

ComplexNumber z = new ComplexNumber(a[0].real, a[0].imag);

I DO appreciate the HINT instead of a "HERE DO THIS...", sincerely! I'm a teacher and a lot of kids HATE hints and some ONLY want "HERE DO THIS..." and it p*sses me off!!!!!!!!!!! So thankyou, thankyou, thankyou, Oli.

Comment: if you remove the default constructor and make `real` and `imag` `final` you can be sure that can't happen again

Comment: Being the teacher and care-giver that I fancy myself as being... "Hey, kids--my error was assigning the REFERENCE of a[0] to z, thus making BOTH a[0] AND z POINT TO THE SAME OBJECT. So sure, changing z changed a[0]." (A bit too much laziness/haste originally overcame the need to think clearly.)

Comment: I just noticed Sinn's advice, which is right on, too. Thanks. But Zapi if I remove the default constructor, how can I make a variable such as sum, whose fields I don't know at compile time, intending to compute sum = cAdd(...some stuff...)?

Comment: You don't need to / should not modify one of the numbers. You also don't need to create an empty placeholder. Use temporary local variables and return a `new ComplexNumber` from `cAdd` http://ideone.com/0MaHY6

Answer (score 2):

When you create your variable `z` in `cAdd`, you refer it to `a[0]`.  Now both `z` and `a[0]` refer to the same object.  Then you change it.

What you should do is make a copy of the first element for `z`, so that when you modify `z`, you don't modify `a[0]`.  Something like this:

```
ComplexNumber z = new ComplexNumber(a[0].real, a[0].imag);
```

Comment: Yeah... I just made a better fix and had to edit my original post since I'm such a newbie--couldn't "answer own question" for 8 hours! SO thanks to EVERYBODY. I'm gonna be on this site  a  LOT! Some day maybe I'll be the helpER instead of the helpEE.